# Swift. After addSubview click listeners dont work

Tags: ios, swift

I have a testVC. TestVC hasnt storyboard, this viewController has XIB file. I show this VC when i have no internet. And logic for a show this VC like this:

```
 let getVC = NoInternetConnectionVC(nibName: "NoInternetConnectionView", bundle: nil)
        if let getWindow = self.window {
            getVC.view.tag = 501
            getVC.view.frame = getWindow.bounds
            getWindow.addSubview(getVC.view)
        }
```

also i have extension for UIViewController

```
extension UIViewController {
     var appDelegate: AppDelegate {
     return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 }
 
 var sceneDelegate: SceneDelegate? {
     guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
         let delegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate else { return nil }
      return delegate
 }
}

extension UIViewController {
 var window: UIWindow? {
     if #available(iOS 13, *) {
         guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
             let delegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate, let window = delegate.window else { return nil }
                return window
     }
     
     guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = delegate.window else { return nil }
     return window
 }
}
```

all clicks in the `TestVC` works if i show this View Controller like this:

```
navController.pushViewController(NoInternetConnectionVC(nibName: "NoInternetConnectionView", bundle: nil), animated: true)
```

but it doesn't suit me. I need to show `NoInternetConnectionVC` like i described above, that is, like this. When i show NoInternetConnectionVC like below all my listeners stop to work

```
 let getVC = NoInternetConnectionVC(nibName: "NoInternetConnectionView", bundle: nil)
            if let getWindow = self.window {
                getVC.view.tag = 501
                getVC.view.frame = getWindow.bounds
                getWindow.addSubview(getVC.view)
            }
```

I tried to add line `isUserInteractionEnabled` to my code, like this

```
if let getWindow = self.window {
            getVC.view.tag = 501
            getVC.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true //added line
            getVC.view.frame = getWindow.bounds
            getWindow.addSubview(getVC.view)
        }
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: After add subview try this : ```let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
        root?.addChild(getVC)
        getVC.didMove(toParent: root!)```

Comment: try this `let getVC = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NoInternetConnectionView", owner: 
    self, options: nil)?.first as? NoInternetConnectionVC ` instead of `let getVC = NoInternetConnectionVC(nibName: "NoInternetConnectionView", bundle: nil)`

Comment: @RajaKishan its a magic! Its works, thanks! you can add this like an answer and i accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just added it as a subview. After adding subview move your controller to parent.

```
if let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController {
    root.addChild(getVC)
    getVC.didMove(toParent: root)
}
```