# swift ios UIButton inside UIView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I made it using a storyboard
I made another view controller for the custom tab bar and created a UIView called innerContents.

And I made another view controller for the setting page in it and put another view controller in innerContents with addSubview.

[CustomTabBar with innerContents UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yKvY.png)

thats innerTabBar main CustomTabBar View Controller page

[other ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Xsr.png)
i will put thats ViewController in innerContents. so i writed addSubView. they are showing but UIButtons are not working. only work ScrollView.

How can I fix it?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZpll.png)

I confirmed that all outlets are connected normally.
But the UIButton inside the UIView inside the UIScrollView inside the UiView of another view controller inside the UiView doesn't work.

mainCustomTabBar Page viewController > innerContents > otherViewController(addSubView) > UIView > UI ScrollView > UIView > UIView > UIButton(it's not working. i want fix that)

````
            if currentPage != 5 {
                currentPage = 5
                print("탭바 클릭 5")
                guard let AppSet = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AppSetViewController") as? AppSetViewController else {return}
                AppSet.view.frame = ContentsView.bounds
                AppSet.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
                AppSet.view.tag = 500
                removeSubview(tag: nowTag)
                nowTag = 500
                ContentsView.addSubview(AppSet.view)
                let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
                root?.addChild(AppSet)
                AppSet.didMove(toParent: root!)
                page5Mode()
                return
            }
        }

//
//  AppSetViewController.swift
//  rael
//
//  Created by HongDaehyeon on 2021/07/08.
// 앱 설정 페이지를 위한 페이지 입니다.

import UIKit

class AppSetViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var ContentView: UIView!{
        didSet {
            self.ContentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var Scrollview: UIScrollView!{
        didSet{
            self.Scrollview.isExclusiveTouch = true
        }
    }
    
    //지갑정보
    @IBAction func walletInfo(_ sender: Any) {
        print("지갑정보")
    }
    
    //알림설정
    @IBAction func alertSet(_ sender: Any) {
        print("알림설정")
    }
    
    //인증방식설정
    @IBAction func authSet(_ sender: Any) {
        print("인증방식설정")
    }
    
    //공지사항
    @IBAction func noticeNav(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SettingsNoticeViewController")
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc!)
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        navController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        navController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    //FAQ
    @IBAction func faqNav(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "FaqViewController")
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc!)
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        navController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        navController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    //고객상담
    @IBAction func serviceCenter(_ sender: Any) {
        print("고객상담")
    }
    
    //약관 및 정책
    @IBAction func termsNav(_ sender: Any) {
        print("약관 및 정책")
    }
    
    //지갑 삭제
    @IBAction func removeWallet(_ sender: Any) {
        print("지갑삭제")
    }
    
    //전화걸기
    @IBAction func callService(_ sender: Any) {
        print("전화걸기")
        let urlString = "tel://1588-8282"
        let numberURL = NSURL(string: urlString)
        UIApplication.shared.open(numberURL! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    //앱정보 로딩
    @IBOutlet var appVer: UILabel!{
        didSet{
            self.appVer.text = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
        }
    }

}```
````

Comment: You have to move your controller as a parent ```AppSet.didMove(toParent: self)```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65808242/14733292

Comment: Please provide your code as text.

Comment: yes i upload code

Comment: i sovled! thank you~ Raja Kishan! thats amazing!